# Renaming multiple variables with different categories using (nested?) loop

Tags: loops, foreach, nested, rename, stata

Suppose that I have a long dataset in Stata, categorized by `vartype`; where `vartype` is in the range of A to D.

```
list var1 var2 var3 vartype in 1/10

    +--------------------------------------+
     |  var1   var2          var3   vartype |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. | 1:Yes      1        900000         A |
  2. | 1:Yes      1             0         C |
  3. | 1:Yes      1             0         A |
  4. | 1:Yes      1       1000000         D |
  5. | 1:Yes      1       8000000         C |
     |--------------------------------------|
  6. | 1:Yes      1       3100000         C |
  7. | 1:Yes      1             0         B |
  8. | 1:Yes      1       4000000         A |
  9. | 1:Yes      1             .         A |
 10. | 1:Yes      1   1.00000e+12         B |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

I want to `reshape` it into wide and `rename` each original variable (`var1 var2 var3`) into different names (say `inpatient outpatient cost`). I also want for each code of `vartype` (A to D) into a different category (`chol diab hyper cancer`) after doing `reshape`.

For example, after `reshape wide`, I will get `var01A, var01B, var01C`, etc. and want to rename them as `inpatient_chol, inpatient_diab, inpatient_hyper`, etc. This should also applied for other variables; `var2 = outpatient` and `var3 = cost`.

For now, all I know is to do these lines below while I am looking for another way(s) such as nested loop or maybe even simpler codes.

```
reshape wide var1 var2 var3, i(hhid pid) j(vartype) string

foreach y in var1 var2 var3 {
rename `y'A `y'cholesterol
rename `y'B `y'diabetes
rename `y'C `y'hypertension
rename `y'D `y'cancer
}

}
foreach x in cholesterol diabetes hypertension cancer {
rename var1`x' has_`x'
rename var2`x' inpatient_`x'
rename var3`x' cost_`x'
}
```

I know I can `rename` and `recode` each variable and each `vartype` before reshaping it into `wide`. I just want to know if there's another way for a wide dataset.

Comment: `rename` allows many different syntaxes. Off-hand I don't see that any offers much improvement on what you already have.

Comment: Your code is clean and clear. Straining to write shorter code could be fun, but it could just seem obfuscated.. Detailed answers proving me wrong would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sir. It appears that I won't be able to prove you wrong as I was just looking for how others might write the codes above.

Comment: :@JR96 has nicely filled in the gap.. Their warnings are apposite too.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks great as is, and would be how I would be inclined to rename the variables in my own code. If you are interested in something shorter (albeit less explicit) you could take advantage of the `*` syntax in the `rename` command. In two lines of code:

```
rename (*A *B *C *D) (*cholesterol *diabetes *hypertension *cancer)
rename (var1* var2* var3*) (has_* inpatient_* cost_*)
```

Just be careful that, for example, you don't have other variables ending with `A` or beginning with `var1` that you do not wish to rename. The complete PDF manual for `rename` has some other handy renaming tricks.

Comment: Nice. Incidentally, if you have preferred pronouns, you are at liberty to declare them.

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply. Will read the manual of -rename groups-.